# Can't open "model/MPI/pose_iter_160000.caffemodel"

Tags: opencv, jupyter-notebook, path, working-directory

help me. Can't open "model/MPI/pose_iter_160000.caffemodel"

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoFile, weightsFile)
      3 inWidth = 368
      4 inHeight = 368

error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1138: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "model/MPI/pose_iter_160000.caffemodel" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromBinaryFile'
```

Comment: try with absolute path for both model & proto

Comment: `assert os.path.exists(protoFile)` and `assert os.path.exists(weightsFile)` and learn about the **current working directory**